# Explain this regex js

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this regex to match some strings:

```
^([^\s](-)?(\d+)?(\.)?(\d+)?)$/
```

I'm confusing about why it's permitted to enter two dots, like `..`

What I understand is that only allowed to put 1 dash or none `(-)?`
Any digits with no limit or none `(\d+)?`
One dot or none `(\.)?`

Why is allowed to put `..` or even `.4.6`?

Testing done in http://www.regextester.com/

Comment: What are the strings you want to match and which are that you do not want to match? `[^\n]` is a negated character class that matches `.`. Add it to `[^\n.]`, and [it will not match](https://regex101.com/r/hN3kO2/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, *`[^\n]` is a negated character class that matches `.`*. and as there is another `(\.)?` pattern, the regex can match 2 consecutive dots (since all of the parts except for `[^\s]` are optional).

In order not to match strings like `.4.5` or `..` you just need to add the `.` to the `[^\n]` negated character class:

```
^([^\s.](-)?(\d+)?(\.)?(\d+)?)$
      ^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hN3kO2/1). This will not let any `.` in the initial capturing group.

You can use a lookahead to only disallow the first character as a dot:

```
^(?!\.)([^\s](-)?(\d+)?(\.)?(\d+)?)$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/hN3kO2/2)

All explanation is available at the online regex testers:

[image]

**In order to match the numbers in the format you expect, use**:

```
^(?:[-]?\d+\.?\d*|-)$
```

Human-readable explanation:

- `^` - start of string and then there are 2 alternatives...
- `[-]?` - optional hyphen
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\.?` - optional dot
- `\d*` - 0 or more digits
- `|` -OR-
- `-` - a hyphen
- `$` - end of string

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hN3kO2/5)

Comment: What I trying to do is match any decimal number including negatives, but not empty string.
1 - Allowed
-1 - Allowed
1. - Allowed
-1. - Allowed
1.0 - Allowed
-1.0 - Allowed

Comment: Sorry, '-' needs to be valid too.
'-' Allowed
'-.' not allowed
'.' not allowed

Please don't spent your whole time, you have already helped a lot

Comment: I'm doing a validation on keyup, user is writting the decimal number, he can starts with negative '-', but he can't start with dot '.', he can finish with dot, but he can't put more than one dot or more than one dash and not a dash before a dot.

Comment: Yeah, i think ^[-]?\d+\.?\d*|-$ will solve!! :) you're a good man.

Comment: And the regex looks very simple, fantastic haha

Comment: I added an explanation of the pattern.

Comment: to be more precise, it missing parentheses, the final regex: 
^ ( [-]?\d+\.?\d*|- ) $ without parentheses before $ and after ^ letters would be allowed.

Comment: @JohnnyWiller: Thanks for the reminder, I was focusing on other details and overlooked this. However, I'd rather use a non-capturing group since we are not interested in the captured text.

Comment: Yes, I even didn't know this 'trick'  '?:'. Very useful! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

`[^\s]` means *anything that is not a whitespace*. This includes dots. Trying to match `..` will get you:

1. `[^\s]` matches `.`
2. `(-)?` doesn't match
3. `(\d+)?` doesn't match
4. `(\.)?` matches `.`
5. `(\d+)?` doesn't match

---

I'll assume you wanted to match numbers (possibly negative/floating):

```
^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

Comment: Exactly right. [Regexplained](http://tinyurl.com/o8zc6hs) might give some clarity

Comment: Omg, how can I didn't notice it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
^([^\s](-)?(\d+)?(\.)?(\d+)?)$/
```

- [Assert position at the beginning of the string](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `([^\s](-)?(\d+)?(\.)?(\d+)?)`

  - [Match any single character that is NOT present in the list below and that is NOT a line break character (line feed)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^\s]`

    - [A single character from the list “\s” (case sensitive)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `\s`
  - [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(-)?`

    - [Between zero and one times, as few or as many times as needed to find the longest match in combination with the other quantifiers or alternatives](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`
    - [Match the character “-” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `-`
  - [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 3](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(\d+)?`

    - [Between zero and one times, as few or as many times as needed to find the longest match in combination with the other quantifiers or alternatives](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`
    - [MySQL does not support any shorthand character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d+`

      - [Between one and unlimited times, as few or as many times as needed to find the longest match in combination with the other quantifiers or alternatives](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 4](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(\.)?`

    - [Between zero and one times, as few or as many times as needed to find the longest match in combination with the other quantifiers or alternatives](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`
    - [Match the character “.” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) `\.`
  - [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 5](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(\d+)?`

    - [Between zero and one times, as few or as many times as needed to find the longest match in combination with the other quantifiers or alternatives](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`
    - [MySQL does not support any shorthand character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d+`

      - [Between one and unlimited times, as few or as many times as needed to find the longest match in combination with the other quantifiers or alternatives](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
- [Assert position at the very end of the string](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$`
- [Match the character “/” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `/`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: Yeah, the reputation goes to the tool :)